# Bash script automation checking if certain version of app is installed or not

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to automate some basics in my Linux Server, I would like to check if the certain version of application like git, python or some other apps are installed or not, if installed than update to latest stable version. Here is my script and it seems I'm missing something:

```
#!/bin/sh

CURRENT_OS=$(hostnamectl   | awk '/Operating/ { print $3 }')
CURRENT_PY=$(python3 -V    | awk '{ print $2 }')
CURRENT_GT=$(git --version | awk '{ print $3 }')

if [ $CURRENT_OS=~"Fedora" || $CURRENT_OS=~"Centos" || $CURRENT_OS=~"Red Hat" ]; then
   echo "➥➥➥ Current System Is Based On $CURRENT_OS"
       sudo dnf clean all
       sudo dnf -y upgrade
   if  [ $CURRENT_PY!="Python 3.8" ]; then
       echo "➥➥➥ Installing Latest Python Release"
       sudo dnf -y install python3.8
   else
       echo "➥➥➥ Latest Python Release Found In System"
   fi
fi
```

Also is there any chance to swap output of command `python3 -V | awk '{ print $2 }'` to 3.8 instead of 3.8.5?
And also how can I refactor the OS release check so either is Red Hat, Centos or Fedora?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify the part about the "OS release check". An example of the expected output for the different situations might help to understand what you need. Additional hints: The variable `CURRENT_PY` will not contain the string `Python` but the version number only. Your check using `!=` might be wrong when there will be a Python version 3.9.

Comment: That is also, my problem. As I can not find a common string for Fedora, Centos, and Red Hat. There fore I'm checking for all 3 possible OS version, I could not found any common things between them.

Comment: As for Python version check I get your point, indeed it well be failed if there will be a 3.9 version. I'm expecting that I can manage the string with regular expressions or so

Comment: Note that `[[ $foo =~ bar ]]` **absolutely requires** the spaces around the `=~` to work correctly. If you just run `[[ something=~something_else ]]` it'll always be unconditionally true, because it's checking whether the single argument that `[[` sees is non-empty.

Comment: Also, you can't use `||` or `=~` in a standard test expression; it needs to be `[[`, not `[`.

Comment: ...because you have multiple separate, unrelated-to-each-other problems in this code with no specific item of focus, I'm voting to close the question as too broad. In the future, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here to catch the easy/mechanical errors.

Comment: "it seems I'm missing something" - This is not a problem statement with which we can help you on Stack Overflow. Does the script cause an error? If so, show that error (add it to the question post). If the script doesn't cause any error, but got unexpected results in some cases, then specify the case, actual output and expected output. See also [ask].

Comment: @Sabretooth Please add more details to your question as I already suggested in my first comment. As I understand your answers in comments you might want to find a more simple check for your OS detection. So write this **in your question**. Tell us your requirements, for example "if the distribution is Red Hat, Centos or Fedora I want to ..., if it is ... I want to ..., if it is something else I want to print an error message." or "if Python is not installed I want to install it, if Python older than 3.8.x is installed I want to update it to the latest version" ...

Comment: @Sabretooth : I suggest to remove the bash tag. You're #! lines says /bin/sh, and you don't use any bashism in your script. Also, please ask only one question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the the Python version using `sed`, e.g.

```
python3 -V | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

The question about the OS release check is not clear. If you only want to have the correct distribution name in the output you can use e.g.

```
echo "➥➥➥ Current System Is Based On $CURRENT_OS"
```

**Edit:**

This was not meant as a fix for a "typo" but my (possibly wrong) interpretation of the unclear question.

If you want to find a common criteria for Red Hat, Centos or Fedora, the existence of a file `/etc/redhat-release` might be an indication for this family of distributions as `/etc/debian_version` is an indication for a Debian based distribution (including e.g. Ubuntu). That means a check like

```
if [ -e /etc/redhat-release ]; then
   echo "➥➥➥ Current system seems to be a distribution of the RedHat family"
   # ...
fi
```

might do what you need.

Please clarify the question.

Comment: Sorry I've corrected that typo in `echo`. Can you also suggest a way to check the OS? For me my approach is not working `[ $CURRENT_OS=~"Fedora" || $CURRENT_OS=~"Centos" || $CURRENT_OS=~"Red Hat" ]` and it should be refactored somehow, but I don't have any clue

Comment: @Sabretooth If your problem is that the OS check does not work, then write this **in your question"". Add enough details to allow us to understand and reproduce your problem. There is already a comment showing errors in your script. You can use shellcheck.net to check a shell script for errors.

Comment: BTW, if the OP _had_ asked a question specifically about how to detect the current OS, we already have entries in the knowledge base it could be closed as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only dealing with CentOS/Fedora/Red Hat you can use **/etc/redhat-release** to find which distribution it is, or also **lsb_release -i** instead of hostnamectl.

Also on Fedora and CentOS you usually also have fedora-release and centos-release files, in addition to redhat-release.

You can also grep ID from /etc/os-release.

```
[user@redhat8 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.1 (Ootpa)
[user@redhat8 ~]# lsb_release -i
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterprise
[user@redhat8 ~]# ls -l /etc/*release
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 501 Sep 25  2019 /etc/os-release
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  45 Sep 25  2019 /etc/redhat-release
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  14 Sep 25  2019 /etc/system-release -> redhat-release
[user@redhat8 ~]# grep -w ID /etc/os-release
ID="rhel"


[user@centos7 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 
[root@centos7 ~]# lsb_release -i
Distributor ID: CentOS
[user@centos7 ~]# ls -l /etc/*release
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  38 Nov 23  2018 /etc/centos-release
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 393 Nov 23  2018 /etc/os-release
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  14 Apr 15 09:05 /etc/redhat-release -> centos-release
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  14 Apr 15 09:05 /etc/system-release -> centos-release
[user@centos7 ~]# grep -w ID /etc/os-release 
ID="centos"


[user@Fedora ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Fedora release 32 (Thirty Two)
[user@Fedora ~]$ lsb_release -i
Distributor ID: Fedora
[user@fedora ~]$ ls -l /etc/*release
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 25 Jun  5 22:00 /etc/fedora-release -> ../usr/lib/fedora-release
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 Jun  5 22:00 /etc/os-release -> ../usr/lib/os-release
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 14 Jun  5 22:00 /etc/redhat-release -> fedora-release
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 14 Jun  5 22:00 /etc/system-release -> fedora-release
[user@fedora ~]$ grep -w ID /etc/os-release
ID=fedora
```

You will need to have **redhat-lsb-core** package installed to have **lsb_release** command on Red Hat based distributions.

Comment: No, not only Fedora family. There is also Debian and others

Comment: I meant /etc/redhat-release file, lsb_release command can be used on any distribution

Comment: Yes, I understand your point, but still there is no common things anyway, so I think my approach of checking OS will be the same. Also ` lsb_release` it is additional software, I'm trying to avoid installing them.

Comment: grep -w ID /etc/os-release should work for all distributions, it should always return centos, fedora or rhel